# Angular syncfusion diagram custom node

Tags: angular, syncfusion

we need the ability to create our own node with the custom events, this node should support click events on the '+' buttons and show an alert window for example.

```
<div class="custom-connector">
  <div class="plus-btn" (click)="callAlertWindow">+</div>
</div>
```

The main thing that we should be able to add this node from the code,

```
this.diagram.add(ShapeFactory.CreateShape(ShapeType.FILTER));
```

How is it possible to do?
[image]

For now I'm able to do this bypassing the HTML template as a string to 'shape.content' property, but in this case I don't have the ability to call a click function, I need to bind it manually by the element id.

```
const node: NodeModel = {
      id: this.name,
      width: 122,
      height: 122,
      shape: {
        type: 'HTML',
        content: '<div class="custom-connector"><div class="plus-btn" id="test">+</div></div>'
      }
};

// Assigning click event
const element = document.getElementById(`test`);
element .onclick = this.LeftPortClick.bind(this);
```

Maybe someone knows a more graceful solution of how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code example, you have rendered HTML node by setting string to the node content property. So, the event binding will not work in string HTML content. Please use HTML node as a template to achieve your requirement.  Please find the sample below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-esr7xm

Regards,

Shyam G

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is dynamic component loading.

the official documentation has a good starter guide on this here [enter link description here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

modifying raw HTML like you have is not generally recommended in Angular.